# Why does Flux.buffer().subscribe() not return immediately?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

Using Project Reactor and Spring WebFlux, I would like to understand why subscribing to a buffered `Flux` does not return immediately. It doesn't return until after I call `FluxSink.complete()`. Although I want to block and wait for completion in this case, I'm surprised that that's the default behavior, and I'm concerned that I've done something wrong.

Why does `Flux.buffer().subscribe()` not return immediately?

Code (simplified):

```java
Flux<MyPojo> flux = Flux.create(sink -> {

    MyPojo data = nextData();
    while (null != data) {

        sink.next(data);

    }

    System.out.println("Finished reading data");
    sink.complete();
    System.out.println("Completed sink");

});

System.out.println("Subscribing...");

flux.buffer(500).subscribe((List<MyPojo> outputList) -> {

    System.out.println(String.format("Going to process %d items...", outputList.size()));
    processSomeOutput(outputList);
    System.out.println("    Processed some output");

});

System.out.println("Returned from subscribe");
```

The output I'm getting:

```
Subscribing...
Going to process 500 items...
    Processed some output
Going to process 500 items...
    Processed some output
Finished reading data
Going to process 99 items...
    Processed some output
Completed sink
Returned from subscribe
```

I expected something like the following, probably because I'm new and don't understand:

```
Subscribing...
Returned from subscribe
Going to process 500 items...
    Processed some output
Going to process 500 items...
    Processed some output
Finished reading data
Going to process 99 items...
    Processed some output
Completed sink
```

Comment: because subscribing is not blocking, if you want to block you call `block` if you want subscribe to the data, asynchronously you call subscribe.

Comment: @Toerktumlare maybe I was unclear. I am calling `subscribe`, but it is blocking. I didn't think a method called `subscribe` would block. I'm wanting to know why.

Comment: without you providing a fully runnbale example, its very hard to explain to you what is actually happening in your code, what is `nextData` what is `processSomeOutput`